# Драйвера для РЕЖИМА MBIM модем FIBO. 860 GL

Tags: консоль

Пожалуйста, откликнитесь, если получиться запустить 860 в MBIM. Через терминал я переключил 860 НА MBIM, теперь модем вечно ребутиться - просит драйвера. Пока еще своими силами я не могу найти...
ОС Windows 10